# Scroll back to the first image when scroll view it's end

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view with 11 images . I want when the last image(11) it's showed , so the scroll view is ended , to get back to the first image. Any ideea how can i do this ?

I was tryed with :

```
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {



    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
}
```

but i don;t have the result wanted.

Comment: Check the contentOffset first to see if you arrive at the end scrolling to top.

Comment: and how to know if it's the end ?

Comment: if contentOffset.y > (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height) then your at the end of the scroll view

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to check whether content in the scroll view ended or not. If its ended set its content offset to 0.

```
CGFloat bottomInset = scrollView.contentInset.bottom;
CGFloat bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height - bottomInset;

if (bottomEdge == scrollView.contentSize.height) {
    // Scroll view is scrolled to bottom


    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y)];

    }
```

Comment: the position it;s seems taht it's changing but the finally its the same image . not the first .

Comment: its code for position change only. You should maintain your image array properly

Answer (score 0):

use these to check you scrolled to bottom or not..i hop it helps

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
  float scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.size.height;
  float scrollContentSizeHeight = self.scrollView.contentSize.height;
  float scrollOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset.y;

  if (scrollOffset == 0)
  {
    // then we are at the top
  }
  else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight)
  {
    // then we are at the end
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y)];
  }
}
```